# Why the printf statement inside the fun(int i) is not executed?

Tags: c, recursion, printf

This is a code that has a recursive loop. I got the output as 199, but the printf statement marked as --A is not executed. Please tell me why??

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int); // function defined

int main()
{
    printf(" %d ", fun(200)); // function called
    return 0;
}

int fun(int i) // entire body of the function
{
    static int d = 0;
    d++;

    if (i % 2)
        return (i++);
    else 
        return fun(fun(i - 1));

    printf("%d ", d);// ------A

} // function fun(int) ends here.
```

Comment: Under which conditions would you expect it to be executed?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: How could it possibly ever be executed?  There is no path to it.  It's what is known as "unreachable code".  If `i%2` is non-zero, it returns `i++`.  Otherwise it returns the nested recursive call result.  It returns in either case.

Answer (score 2):

From :

```
if ( i%2 ) return (i++);
else return fun(fun( i - 1 ));
```

Both parts are returning if the function converges. So `printf` is unreachable code.

Comment: Yup.. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Because `return` ends current function.

Answer (score 1):

`return` returns control of the program to the calling function. So nothing after `return` is called inside a function is executed. If you want the `printf` to be called, put it before `return`.